# Replacing string values in 2d array with numbers

Tags: python, arrays, loops, replace

[Imported Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AiN3.png)

Hi,

I'm using the read_csv function in python to import data from a url. The data I'm importing consists of a column of character/string with the other columns consisting of numbers. Is there any way to replace the first column with numbers as well? For example, replace M with 1, F with 2 and I with 3? I'm thinking of some kind of loop with conditional statements but I don't really know the proper syntax with python.

```
    While i less than number of rows
       If X[i][0] == 'M' 
       X[i][0] = 1

       Else X[i][0] =='F'
       X[i][0] == 2
      i=i+1
```

Comment: at least you should try to write *some kind of loop with conditional statements*

Comment: Sorry, edited that

Comment: So your data is like `[['M', ...], ['F', ....], ['F', ....]]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: There are plenty of resources for learning basic Python (e.g. [this](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/)), you really should try by yourself first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it and give it a try

Comment: Which `read_csv()` function? It is not part of the standard library. But `pandas` has such a function. And with `pandas`' data frame you don't want to manually write loops if not absolute necessary.  And in this case it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing `pandas` as library from the `read_csv()` function name and the formatting of the data in the image.

With `pandas` you don't want to use explicit loops written in Python code but the tools offered by `pandas`.  In this case the `map()` method on data frames.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
df.sex = df.sex.map({'M': 1, 'F': 2, 'I': 3})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```